# Why doesn't my if/else exit the loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The problem starts at if statement ("Did you apply for Housing Allowance allowance for this month? yes/no");
After getting the answer from user the app still loops again.

Why doesn't my if/else exit the loop?
All my logic is okay except the if statement won't break at all
I have tried to use break statement to jump the if/else and stop the code from infinite run but it also  didn't work.

What am I missing?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        double basic_salary, tax, KWSP, housing_allowance, holder;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = null;

        System.out.println("Enter Basic Salary Of Employee: ");
        basic_salary = scan.nextDouble();

        do {

            if (basic_salary <= 6000 && basic_salary >= 1) {

                tax = 0.10 * basic_salary;
                System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
                housing_allowance = 0.5 * basic_salary;
            } else if (basic_salary >= 6001 && basic_salary <= 10000) {

                tax = 0.20 * basic_salary;
                System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
                housing_allowance = 0.5 * basic_salary;;
            } else if (basic_salary >= 10001 && basic_salary <= 14000) {

                tax = 0.25 * basic_salary;
                System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
                housing_allowance = 0.3 * basic_salary;;
            } else {

                tax = 0.30 * basic_salary;
                System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
                housing_allowance = 0.3 * basic_salary;;
            }


            System.out.println("Type the amount For KWSP contribution 11% or 13%  ONLY");
            KWSP = scan.nextDouble();
            holder = KWSP / 100;
            KWSP = holder * basic_salary;
            System.out.println("KWSP contribution= " + KWSP + " $");



            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Did you apply for Housing Allowance allowance for this month? yes/no");
            answer = input.nextLine();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Housing Allowance: " + housing_allowance + " $");
                System.out.println("KWSP:contribution: " + KWSP + " $");
                System.out.println("Tax:contribution : " + housing_allowance + " $");
                System.out.println("Gross Salary Of Employee: " + (KWSP + housing_allowance + tax) + " $");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");


            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("KWSP:contribution: " + KWSP + " $");
                System.out.println("Tax:contribution : " + housing_allowance + " $");
                System.out.println("Gross Salary Of Employee: " + (KWSP + tax) + " /n");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("");



            } else {
                break;
            }

        } while (basic_salary > 0); //while loop

        System.out.println("salary cannot be Zero or Negative");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the user would have to put in something other than "yes" or "no" for the code to get to `break`?  This is a problem that you could solve by yourself with a debugger, in fact more easily than asking here.

Comment: Don't create Scanner handling System.in in each iteration. Create it once at start of main method and use it when you need it.

Comment: but basic_salary  is the first to validate before the entering loop, how can I change that

Comment: Exactly you need return a value to end the loop in each if statement.

Comment: Tip: If you write smaller functions and compose them together to achieve the functionality you want, you'll likely find it easier to debug.

Comment: @dacijilole3030 - return basic_salary iquals to 0. In the stament that you want to end the loop, I mean: else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){... basic_salary = 0; }

Comment: at which point or condition would you like your code to exit the loop?

Comment: There is something called debugging. which is the process of finding problems by going through the code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking input the `basic_salary` and then running a do-while loop till `basic_salary > 0` and not modifying `basic_salary` anywhere

This condition will not turn false, until user inputs 0 or some negative value itself.

I am not sure what you want to achieve, what's your logic is.
If you want to simply print the messages after making calculations then maybe you can use simple if-else condition instead of do-while loop.

Maybe something like this :

```
if (basic_salary > 0) {
    //do your calculation and printing here
} else {
    //print basic_salary less than 0 error message
    System.out.println("salary cannot be Zero or Negative");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your while statement it seems that you want to break the loop when the salary is != 0.

So you could change your condition for something like this:

```
while !(basic_salary > 0); //while loop
```

And maybe write your `System.out.println` at the beginning of your loop.

```
System.out.println("salary cannot be Zero or Negative");
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code so it can work now. But don't just blindly use it, try to read it and understand why does it work.
Check it and ask further questions, if any.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double basic_salary, tax, KWSP, housing_allowance, holder;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Basic Salary Of Employee: ");
        basic_salary = scan.nextDouble();
        if (basic_salary <= 0) {
            housing_allowance = 0;
            tax = 0;
            System.out.println("salary cannot be Zero or Negative");

        } else if (basic_salary <= 6000 && basic_salary >= 1) {

            tax = 0.10 * basic_salary;
            System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
            housing_allowance = 0.5 * basic_salary;
        } else if (basic_salary >= 6001 && basic_salary <= 10000) {

            tax = 0.20 * basic_salary;
            System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
            housing_allowance = 0.5 * basic_salary;
        } else if (basic_salary >= 10001 && basic_salary <= 14000) {

            tax = 0.25 * basic_salary;
            System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
            housing_allowance = 0.3 * basic_salary;
        } else {

            tax = 0.30 * basic_salary;
            System.out.println("The compulsory tax =  " + tax + " $");
            housing_allowance = 0.3 * basic_salary;
        }
    }
    while (basic_salary <= 0);

    do {
        System.out.println("Type the amount For KWSP contribution 11% or 13%  ONLY");
        KWSP = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    while (!(KWSP == 11 || KWSP == 13));

    holder = KWSP / 100;
    KWSP = holder * basic_salary;
    System.out.println("KWSP contribution= " + KWSP + " $");

    do {
        System.out.println("Did you apply for Housing Allowance allowance for this month? yes/no");
        answer = scan.next();
    }
    while (!(answer.equals("yes") || answer.equals("no"))) ;

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Housing Allowance: " + housing_allowance + " $");
        System.out.println("KWSP:contribution: " + KWSP + " $");
        System.out.println("Tax:contribution : " + housing_allowance + " $");
        System.out.println("Gross Salary Of Employee: " + (KWSP + housing_allowance + tax) + " $");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("KWSP:contribution: " + KWSP + " $");
        System.out.println("Tax:contribution : " + housing_allowance + " $");
        System.out.println("Gross Salary Of Employee: " + (KWSP + tax) + " /n");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```